# Research Project

Tags: product-research

Hi Jay

I'm studying a Bachelor of Recording Arts and have a research project I have to complete.

I stumbled upon this website and saw that a while ago you gave a guy this idea for a research project -

*Design sound for an older movie scene/trailer using new sounds recorded at the highest bitrate and sample rate available (most likely 24bit/192kHz), then using some creative pitch shifting and/or other processing, discuss why this newer technology allows you more creativity and makes the end result "better".*

I'm thinking off doing this for my research project and I wanted to ask whether or not you have any suggestions as to what movies in particular you think could be done "better" with newer recorded sounds.

Also if you had any other research ideas then don't hesitate.

Cheers,

Denby Strange

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at whether that project with that kind of brief ever got done, and if it was, what were the propositions, what were the outcomes and how was it presented, before jumping at something like that. And see whether someone has done something similar. That quote sounds far too general, broad and technical to me that I personally fail to see the point of this kind of "research", mainly because the effects/outcomes of technological development and the technology itself (in the quote's case: sample rates, bit depth(?), pitch-shifting, general audio DSP) are self-explanatory and "standard" from a creative viewpoint. Unless you wish to analyze their "goodness" from a quantitative standpoint, but this question doesn't sound like it.

However, if you wish to improve a soundtrack that's been produced prior to the substantial technologies (fully computer-based recording and production) that we have today, then I think you could pick any piece of media that motivates you and that's been produced without computers and otherwise with far less sophisticated and more fundamental (analog, manual) ways (<- that's what you'd use as an antithesis prior to demonstrating that today's technology allows improved sound quality and richer soundtracks in your chosen case). But even in this case, "researching" and proposing/stating that "today's technology allows us to produce better audio and be more creative" and then going on to prove it is a straightforward statement that "we all know". As an individual demonstration and exploration it's ok, of course, but as a "research project", it doesn't really sound useful(?) and it's vague without a quantitative or scientific aspect to support it. Or would it be more useful to expand on what the requirements are for this research project, or is it more like a personal, practical/project-based thesis?

Comment: @Internet So it's a 12,000 word research project/dissertation on a topic of my choice. The project will be based on a hypothesis of which I'll be trying to confirm. It can be practical or theory based or both. From what I understand, it should be a new idea or a different take on established research. The 12,000 words are covering the journey I took when researching my hypothesis. I wanted to base mine on sound in the film industry, as this is where I want to have a career, but have been struggling to find an area in which any type of meaningful research can be fulfilled.

Comment: @Denby Yeah, it's difficult as art research tends to be a bit scarce. Or when it's meaningful, it's often cross-discipline or done from a science's point of view e.g. psychology. I don't know if that helps, but if you're really into showing something, then you may want to tie your research project to e.g. something psychological or statistical (surveys), so that you get more powerful tools to actually show something.

Comment: @Denby Often I find that art theses may skip scientific methods totally and the point of the thesis becomes mainly individual and often summarizing of existing research/literacy with some invidividual contribution often in the form of a practical demonstration. I.e. the focus tends to be on just the individual showing that he/she has learned something. But your brief sounds like "the real deal", unless they're always like that and students still fill in individual summarizing "research" without much/any original outcomes. 

Comment: @Denby You may want to review some journals of art research and older theses in the specific subdomains that interest you to get an idea of what others are doing and what's been done. It might spark you to see new connections in something or a hole that you can fill. And you also get an idea of how others undertake the quest of proving something / presenting something new.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to study the impact that higher sampling rates and greater bit depths have had on film production, specifically the take up and acceptance.

If you watch the Sound Works collection video on the Hobbit there is a reference to recording new sounds with higher sample rates and bit depths in order to refresh the library, see 01:49 onwards.

http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/hobbit

Comment: @Iain Thats a great idea! So as I mentioned in the above answer, I need to come up with a hypothesis that will form the basis of my research project. For example something like 'that higher sampling rates and greater bit depths have enabled cinematic sound to have a greater impact on film production'. Thoughts?

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to show that there has been a greater impact on film.  You need to do a bit more reading before you come up with a hypothesis.  I suggest an exploratory piece of work where you pose a research question and answer it, rather than set an hypothesis and try to prove or disprove it.

From my experience reduced bit depths and lower sample rates have also have benefited cinematic sound designers through harmonic generation.  Higher sample rates and greater bit rates are just another tool.

Answer (score 0):

How about the old Tron and Star wars films?